# Exports to Excel cause intermittent integer to decimal conversion

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Does anyone know why when exporting data to Excel, some of the digits are changed from whole numbers or integers to decimals with 5 or more digits. For instance, 800 will become 799.999996 or it might become 800.00005. It doesn't do it for every cell with a number--there appears to be no consistency whatsoever.

Is there a way to keep this from happening or is it something that is inherent in databases?

This question has bugged the daylights out of me for years, and I can't seem to find an answer anywhere, but maybe someone here will now.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! From what database(s) were you exporting when you observed this problem?

Comment: This shouldn't happen, so it's not "something inherent to databases".  How are you "exporting to Excel" exactly, and from what?  Have you confirmed the raw data in the DB isn't actually a decimal?  Are you processing the data at all before importing into Excel?

Comment: Is the data you are exporting really exactly 800, or does it merely appear to be 800 in the record you are looking at?  What kind of database and what kind of record are you looking at in the original?  How, exactly, are doing the export.

Comment: I have this happen in a number of different types of databases, but most often from Oracle and Sybase. And yes, the numbers when queried from the database are stored as whole numbers.

Comment: If you consider the answer below to be suitable, then please click the gray tick beside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We humans are used to using "base ten" to represent numbers.

This sets some specific constants to be "irrational" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number) for example: 
1/3, 1/7, square root two, PI are a few of them.

Now if you choose to use base two instead (as computers do), the irrational numbers change; e.g. 1/10 is one, consisting of "0.000110011" in the "calculator" I have on Ubuntu; when switched to "programming and binary (base two) mode. The 1's to the right of the decimal point now represent 1/16+1/32+1/256+1/512 which equals "0.099609375" in decimal - which is quite close to 1/10, but not exactly.

The very same is true for a set of values. Which? I cannot tell, but I'm quite sure there are a number of them.

Now on top of this add the effects of a limited precision floating point representation e.g. using only 32 bits (ref: format description [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32), compare to "8+E2" for decimal).

*1/10 (decimal) = 0.0 0011 0011 0011 0011 ... (binary)*

*For what it is worth: 800 represented as binary shouldn't show up with strange decimals; as 8 =2^3 and 2 is 2^0, both simple base two numbers, stored as such in floating point representation internally in computers.*

Comment: Okay, that helps some, but it doesn't explain why this happens so intermittently. For instance, why would 800 export out as 799.999936 in one export, but as 800 in another export out of the same database?

Comment: To explain that you may need to check what you actually have got in your database. But anyway you really should *expect* to get minor occasional errors like this; numbers in computers are not *exact*. Unless your software does use a math library which has an explicitly stated "arbitrary precision" (this is NOT the case for Excel). But then such a library probably has limitations too, due to the above.